# Display "in stock" product variation custom attribute values in WooCommerce category archives

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I have a store with woocommerce and I want to show the available size at the category page. I did that, but I want sizes not in stock to not show. In this moment on category page are listed all sizes assigned to the product. I want to display only the ones that have variations asigned to them that are in stock.

I tried adding more attributes to **`wc_get_product_terms`** but with no success. This is the current code, working pretty well but it's not what I want:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_display_post_meta', 9 );

function custom_display_post_meta() {
    global $product;

    //Doing this for more types of sizes, so list only if it's necesarry
    $size = $product->get_attribute('pa_size');
    if( $size )
    {
        $values = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_size', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
        echo implode( ', ', $values );
    }
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go through the **variations stock quantity**, to display only **"in stock" sizes** for each variable products, in WooCommerce **category archives** pages, this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'displaying_sizes_in_stock', 9 );
function displaying_sizes_in_stock() {
    global $product;

    // HERE, set your attribute taxonomy (once)
    $attr_taxonomy = 'pa_size';

    $size = $product->get_attribute( $attr_taxonomy );

    // Targeting variable products with size attribute (on product category archives)
    if( $product->is_type('variable') && $size && is_product_category() ){
        $variations = $product->get_available_variations( );

        // Product ID - compatibility with WC +3
        $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

        // Iterating Through all available variation for that product
        foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $values ){
            // Get an instance of WC_Product_Variation object
            $variation_obj = wc_get_product( $values['variation_id'] );
            // get the defined stock quantity
            $stock_quantity = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();
            if( ! $stock_quantity )
                $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
            // When product variation is in stock
            if( $stock_quantity > 0 && $stock_quantity ){
                // Get the variation attributtes
                $variation_attributes = $variation_obj->get_variation_attributes();
                // For "size" attribute only
                if( array_key_exists( "attribute_$attr_taxonomy", $variation_attributes) ){
                    // Get the term slug
                    $attr_slug = $variation_attributes["attribute_$attr_taxonomy"];
                    // Get an instance of WP_Term object
                    $term_obj = get_term_by( 'slug', $attr_slug, $attr_taxonomy );
                    // Get the attribute name
                    $attr_name[] = $term_obj->name;
                }
            }
        }
        // Output the "sizes" that have stock
        echo implode( ', ', array_unique( $attr_name ) ) . ' ';
    }
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works for wooCommerce versions 3+.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I wasn't searching in the right place. Thank you very much !